# How to apply to "Get balance"?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-credits, credits, userinfo

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/
Section "Get Balance"

"You can apply here" links to
http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=19705
which is unavailable.

How can I apply?

I need it for casino reviews site: [HolyMolyCasinos](https://holymolycasinos.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the "Apply page" in Google. Turned out that Google is smarter than Facebook :)
https://www.facebook.com/help/contact_us.php?id=157379954315015